# SplitContainer error

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I've got this error report:

```
Collection is read only.
at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.SplitContainerTypedControlCollection.SetChildIndexInternal(Control child, Int32 newIndex)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex(Control child, Int32 newIndex)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateChildControlIndex(Control ctl)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I have no idea what it is, and search just gave me one msdn post without solution. Any ideas? What this exception is about at all, I'll probably find the way to fix it if I find some general description how this can happen?

Comment: This is error report. Code has more than 10.000 lines, and this doesn't lead to any specific part.

So question is does anyone have idea why this might happen at all?

Comment: The error indicates you are trying to assign to or remove items from a collection where such an operation is not permitted.  It is likely to be an `IEnumberable` or a similar read only interface.

Comment: I realize that, but how can it be done with SplitContainer? My guess is that this is some internal error in SplitContainer implementation in .net, but still probably it happens because of something and there is a way to work around it.

Comment: You could find all references to the split container in question and simply post the code related to it such as the constructor and the initialization.

Comment: That SplitContainer has 67 refrences in the code. OK, that is postable, but it is highly unlikely to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, you are trying to delete the internal panels of the SplitContainer controls

Something like this reproduces the error:

```
splitContainer1.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
```

You will have to search in your code where you are trying to delete or remove child controls.  Could easily be from a recursive method.

Comment: I have FlowLayoutPanel inside one container of SplitContainer. It has some removal of its controls. But it shouldn't count, right? I'll double check, but SplitContainer itself doesn't have any removal of its first-child controls...

Comment: @IvanIčin SplitContainer has a Controls property, hidden with Attributes from the designer and code, but it's there.  You would have to post the code that causes the error for us to help.

Comment: I know that, I just say there is no splitContainer.Controls.Remove... Nor splitContainer.Panel1.Controls.Remove. Nor splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Remove.

Comment: @IvanIčin But what code causes the exception to happen?  Look for code that is simply `Controls.Remove` or just `Dispose`.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because at least it shows how one can raise this exception. However, there is not a trace of such thing in my code, so I strongly believe it is a bug in .net framework (you can also see from the bug report that that stack trace reffers just to .net framework classes, nothing from my code is there)

Comment: @IvanIčin Well, looking at your error message more closely, are you doing something with a NativeWindow class?

Comment: SplitContainer is just generic SplitContainer. Inside its Panel2 it hosts FlowLayoutPanel, and inside FlowLayoutPanel there are custom controls that have among other thing custom .nsb derived from NativeWindow. But I don't think it could lead to this exception?

Comment: @IvanIčin This guy had the same problem almost exactly as you describe it [Exception: Collection is read only when closing Form](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6093519c-5281-4ff3-b4d7-913edb4b635f/winforms-exception-collection-is-read-only-when-closing-form).  Unfortunately, no more info there.  Assuming this only happens on client machines, what operating system does this error happen on?

Comment: According to bug report it is Windows 8 (or Windows Server 2013) - v6.2.9200.0, .net is v4.0.30319. My app works in x86 mode, so I don't think it matters if it is 64-bit, and I am unsure if I can detect that (IntPtr.Size is 4, but I think it always is).

Yes I have seen that post, I have mentioned that in question (without referral as it wasn't helpful)